# How show a Dialog for each member of a List?

Tags: android, list, arraylist, dialog

I have a list of Card( Card has Question and Answer)

```
List<Card> cards = db.getAnswerableCards(userid);
```

how can i show a Dialog for each member of cards?

I used below code but it just work for the last Card

```
final Dialog dialogtypeanswer = new Dialog(this, R.style.dialogcatedit);
List<Card> cards = db.getAnswerableCards(userid);
TextView question = (TextView) dialogtypeanswer.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
final EditText answer = (EditText) dialogtypeanswer.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
Button compare = (Button) dialogtypeanswer.findViewById(R.id.button1);
dialogtypeanswer.show();

 for (final Card card : cards) {
     question.setText(card.getQuestion());
     compare.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
      if(card.getAnswer().equals(answer.getText())){
        db.updateCardState(card.getId(),userid,b.getStateofCard(userid,card.getId())+1);
     }else{
        db.updateCardState(card.getId(), userid, 0);
     }
   }
  });
 }
dialogtypeanswer.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looping through all your cards, setting the text and then *immediately* going to the next card. You need to add code to your `OnClickListener` to wait for the user to finish before advancing to the next card.

Edit: some example code (Disclaimer: I did not test this).

First get your list iterator and call the method to display the first card:

```
ListIterator<Card> iterator = cards.listIterator();
Card card = iterator.next();
showCard(card); // this will contain all your dialog logic
```

In the onClickListener, advance the iterator and display the dialog with the next card:

```
new OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {
    if(card.getAnswer().equals(answer.getText())){
      db.updateCardState(card.getId(),userid,b.getStateofCard(userid,card.getId())+1);
    }else{
      db.updateCardState(card.getId(), userid, 0);
    }
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
      Card c = iterator.next();
      showCard(c);
    }
    dialog.dismiss();
  }
}
```

Comment: I put `question.setText(card.getQuestion());` in `onClicListener` but does not work!

Comment: @muhammad-arbabi I added a code example. I hope it helps!